# django filter and update

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

update:
I did some test for `select_for_update`. I am using django 1.8.12. I run the following functions in different shell, connecting to my local mariadb (engine is InnoDB). seems `select_for_update` locks other row as well? Not sure if I did testing in correct way:

```
def with_sleep(resource):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            resource = resourceA.objects.select_for_update().filter(A=resource).first()
            print('before sleep')
            time.sleep(10)
            print('after sleep')
            resource.available = False
            resource.save()
            return True
    except:
            handle_exception()

def withouth_sleep(resource):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            print('try')
            resource = resourceA.objects.select_for_update().filter(A=resource).first()
            print('get resource')
            resource.available = False
            print('save')
            resource.save()
            return True
    except:
            handle_exception()
```

I call the `with_sleep(resource1)` function first and call then `without_sleep(resource2)`. `resource1` and `resource2` are different resources in my model. From the shell, I saw the second function blocked after `try` till the first function awake from sleep. Is that mean row of resource2 is also locked?

The question might sound stupid. Thanks for any advise or any change for testing.

original question:
I have a resource model which checks if a resource is available or not, and it runs multiple celery workers in 2 servers to retrieve the next available resource each time. If available, change it's status to unavailable and assign to the task.

For example:

```
Class resourceA(model.Model):
    A = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Every time, I just want to pick the next available resource and assign to task.
If I do

```
resource = resourceA.objects.filter(available=True).first()
if resource:
    resource.available=False
    resource.save()
```

Then there is a chance that other workers might pick up the same resource and try to update it.

Django has `select_for_update` to lock the entries. However, I don't want to lock and update all the available resources.

Please suggest if is there any way so that I can retrieve and update in one shot?

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: @Asion I am using sqlite for testing now and will use mysql in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select_for_update` will lock the rows only, so with `first()` in your query there will be only one row locked.

Thus — use `select_for_update`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I did some tests with select_for_update. Seems not working as expected. Please check the update.

Comment: From what I see in your update, you atomising the same row in the database, `first()`. In this case it is the expected behaviour. The row is locked until released. Try doing it with `last()` in the `withouth_sleep` block. If it works as expected (executed instantly) — that's what you want, only the row you work with is locked.

Comment: actually, I passed 2 different resources to those functions in the update just to test the 'select_for_update'. When calling '.filter()', they actually selected different rows. I think by using '.first()' and '.last()', they should have the same behaviour and they did.